# Month not displaying with this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am trying to get the month element show up on the following html, and it's showing me wrong number, I need to display the name of the month instead of number.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="card-expiration-date">
    <label>Expires</label>
     <div></div>
 </div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
$('#card-expiration-month, #card-expiration-year').change(function(){
    m = $('#card-expiration-month option').index($('#card-expiration-month option:selected'));
    m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    y = $('#card-expiration-year').val().substr(2,2);
    $('.card-expiration-date div').html(m + '/' + y);
})
```

This is my code in Laravel 5.2

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-expiration">
  <label for="card-expiration-month">Expiration date</label>
  {{ Form::selectMonth(null, null, ['id' => 'card-expiration-month','data-stripe' => 'exp-month']) }}
  {{ Form::selectYear(null, date('Y'), date('Y') + 10, null, ['id' => 'card-expiration-year','data-stripe' => 'exp-year']  ) }}
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the rendered html? Is the month number off by one?

Comment: Yes it's 01/2016 for February

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, though I don't know for sure, the form elements that you're generating via Laravel and/or Stripe are using a zero based index for the month.

For example:

```
January = 0
February = 1
March = 2
```

As far as getting the month name you'll likely need to create an array and use the month index you have. Maybe something like this?

```js
var month_names = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ];
var month_index = $('#card-expiration-month option').index($('#card-expiration-month option:selected'));
var month = month_names[ month_index ];
var year = $('#card-expiration-year').val().substr(2,2);
var expires = month + ' ' + year;
```

### Update

After some discussion in the comments it appears the OP needed to adjust the month's index value so it would represent the human readable number value representing the month.

Solution is to add one `+ 1` to the month's index value.

```js
m = m + 1;
m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
```

Comment: I just need to show the numbers, don't have space for full month.

Comment: **What?** You have this at the beginning of your post, _"...I need to display the name of the month instead of number."_

Comment: Nvm, I am using laravel Element, which displays Month as name, but index of that value is in number.

Comment: Well, if you need the proper number, simply add one `+ 1` before you optionally add a leading zero since the months are using a zero based index. `m = m + 1` then `m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;`.